# Tag synonyms and romanization

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should anime / manga names / tags be in English (international title) or romanized Japanese?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/should-anime-manga-names-tags-be-in-english-international-title-or-romaniz)

It seems that there are already some duplicate tags, such as [ruroni-kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruroni-kenshin) and [rurouni-kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rurouni-kenshin) (and another one just by the name of [kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kenshin)). How should we act regarding different romanizations of the Japanese titles? I'm thinking that the first one should be suppressed, and everything tagged with it retagged with the second tag. Or maybe different spellings are allowed and synonyms created?

Also, there are some like [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations) and [comparison-of-media](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison-of-media). Should these be linked somehow? Or one of them suppressed?

Comment: "and everything tagged with it retagged with the second tag" -- that's exactly what tag-synonyms do. If we make the first a synonym of the second, it will at all places be replaced with that.

Comment: ok, I am new to the whole tagging thing

Answer (score 7):

Considering that accents are not allowed in tags, I would say that we should use the non-accented romanized spelling for titles. *Rurōni Kenshin* with one "o" is only appropriate because of the use of Hepburn-style romanization using the macron for the long vowel. *Rurouni Kenshin* is the most correct form that we can use in the tagging system, so I think we should default to that.

Regarding [kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kenshin) or any other common shortenings for series names (for example, [eva](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eva) for [neon-genesis-evangelion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neon-genesis-evangelion) or [gits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gits) for [ghost-in-the-shell](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell)), we should synonimize them with the proper titles.

Comment: I understand that this [tag:kenshin] tag refers to the character, rather than the anime. But still, I think the question should be retagged.

Comment: @JNat I agree, it should be retagged to the series in that case rather than the character.

Comment: apparently i was already tagged as [tag:rurouni-kenshin] too. So I removed the [tag:kenshin] tag and put the [tag:characters] tag instead.

Comment: I prefer the longer version for those tags, actually...

Comment: @Alenanno That's what I meant, synonimize the short versions to the long form, proper titles.