# Regarding tag sprawl

Tags: discussion, tags

Following what was discussed in [this](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/rename-tag-naruto-to-naruto-shippuuden) and [this](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/tag-synonyms-and-romanization) Meta posts, I think the tag sprawl needs to be contained. Much like we should not have separate tags for the Naruto and the Naruto Shippuuden series, there are some tags on the main site that perhaps should be dealt with:

- There are [dragonball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-z) and [dragonball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-gt) tags, but amazingly enough there is no [dragonball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball) tag (but it will most likely appear)
- There is a [ghost-in-the-shell](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell) tag, but there is also a [ghost-in-the-shell-sac](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-sac)
- There is a [rurouni-kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rurouni-kenshin) tag, and a [ruroni-kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruroni-kenshin) tag
- There is a [cardcaptors](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardcaptors) and a [cardcaptor-sakura](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardcaptor-sakura) tag

However:

- Naruto Shippuuden, is 'contained' in [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto)
- Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, is 'contained' in [fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist)
- The Rebuild Series of Evangelion, The Death & Rebirth of Evangelion, are/will be 'contained' in [neon-genesis-evangelion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neon-genesis-evangelion)

The ones stated in the first list have specific tags for each specific series/movie or have different spellings.
**What should be the site's position in this matter?**

There is also [this debate](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/should-minimalistic-tags-and-synomoms-be-used-for-anime-with-different-series), but I do not think it is exactly the same thing. Plus, [this one](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-dragon-ball-series) concerning Dragonball. I think these discussions should be condensed into this one. However, if you think this is a redundant post close it!

Comment: I think that simplicity is the best, less tags are more searchable.

Comment: I agree with you. I think the tag should have the franchise name, and the specific media or series of the franchise should be specified in-question/title.

Comment: Initiate Tag Instrumentality!

Answer (score 4):

(Just to rewrite it officially)

I think that less tags are better in most cases. They are more searchable, and are sufficient in most cases.

However, to distinguish, it's better to write something specific in the title, for example, as [Veger](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/veger) mentioned in [this question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-dragon-ball-series), he doesn't want to read questions regarding Dragonball GT (which I can understand), so writing "Dragon Ball GT" somewhere in the title should be enough (Example: [How involved was Akira Toriyama in the production of Dragon Ball GT?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/361/dragon-ball-gt-made-by-fans)).

Also, too many Tags can lead to confusion, too, as seen [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/539/what-is-the-difference-between-tachikoma-and-fuchikoma), where the [ghost-in-the-shell-sac](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-sac)-Tag was chosen, while the normal [ghost-in-the-shell](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell)-Tag was better.

However, the example [rurouni-kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rurouni-kenshin) <-> [ruroni-kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruroni-kenshin) is a good candidate for a synonym, like Tags with different spellings in japanese and western languages. I have no other example, but different spellings should are synonyms (see comments below).

Comment: '*[tag:rurouni-kenshin] <-> [tag:ruroni-kenshin] is a good candidate*' -> better make this more general: as in the Western spelling is used for the tag and the Japansese spelling is used as synonym, so people are able to use both. (or something like that)

Comment: Also, [cardcaptors](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardcaptors) is what [cardcaptor-sakura](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardcaptor-sakura) is known in the US, and (I believe) nowhere else. So, also a synonym?