# What are the requirements to decide if the tag will get his english or his japanese name?

Tags: support, tags

I've recently created the tag of [kiseijuu-sei-no-kakuritsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiseijuu-sei-no-kakuritsu) but very quickly after that someone has changed it to [parasyte](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parasyte) (the english name).

I know there are a lot of names the community already has change their names from the english to the japanese, like [wen-they-cry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wen-they-cry) to [higurashi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higurashi) or [samurai-x](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samurai-x) to [rurouni-kenshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rurouni-kenshin)"Rurouni Kenshin for example.

What I want to know is why this time it has been changed to the english one and not remain the japanese instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/49) a long time ago, and the post seems to suggest no consensus was reached (since there's a lot of debate on comments as well, and ultimately no answer was accepted). Further debate may have taken place in chat, because I seem to recall that in the end the decision was to make whichever title was more popular the one we use. So basically, it would mean that each case should be individually assessed.
Nevertheless, I have now created a synonym for that, and whichever language we choose for each tag, the advisable thing to do would be to create a synonym for the alternative title.

Also, if you notice the [edit description](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/15191/2) when the tag on you question was changed, it says "Retagging to [parasyte] since it's better known in English by that title".
We cannot forget we're an English language community, so we should keep in mind what the best known title is for (most) English speakers.

As for you knowing and choosing which of the title is more popular, I say that's the least of our problems. If you end up creating a tag with the less popular title, either someone who is sure the other title is more popular will retag it for you; or if people are unsure, the matter will most certainly pop up in our main chat room, and a consensus will generally be reached (this has happened some times in the past).

Comment: In this case I think parasyte is much more well known than kiseijuu-sei-no-kakuritsu. But how can you determine every time which one is more popular?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address that issue.